# SpriteKit Animations

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

I have this code that does the animation that I want to be executed over the entire time I'm holding down a button that I've created. However I would like this to repeat while the button is being held. Once I've let go it would return the sprite back to a standing position.

```
func runForward()
{
    let run = SKAction.animateWithTextures([
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk1"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk2"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk3"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk4")
    ], timePerFrame: 0.09)
    
    _hero!.runAction(run)
}
```

If I put this code inside of update it updates every frame causing the animation to only finish once I lift my finger off the button. If I start this animation once the button is clicked it only performs it at the very beginning. I was wondering how I get this to run consecutively until I lift my finger off the button.

Heres the code of the button which is just a Sprite Node placed on screen.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */    
    // Loop over all the touches in this event
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        // Get the location of the touch in this scene
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        // Check if the location of the touch is within the button's        
        if (right.containsPoint(location)) {
            _right = true
            runForward()
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    _right = false
}
```

Comment: Please add proper code highlighting, this is practically unreadable.

Comment: Sorry I realized that after I posted it but just got it set into a better format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is start the animation when your touch begins (`touchesBegan`) and end the animation when your touch ends (`touchesEnded`).

Therefore, you should perform an action that repeats forever once your touch begins. This action will have a key (or a name). Once your touch ends, you can use the key (or name) to cancel the action that is running forever (thus it will stop the animation)

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let run = SKAction.animateWithTextures([
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk1"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk2"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk3"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk4")
            ], timePerFrame: 0.09)
        hero.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([
                        run,
                        SKAction.waitForDuration(0.001)
                        ])
                        ), withKey: "heroRunning"
                    )
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
   for touch: AnyObject in touches {
      hero.removeActionForKey("heroRunning")
   }
}
```